# Isabelle: How can I position fixed arguments in mixfix notation?

Tags: syntax, isabelle

Say I have the following definition of a reflexive and transitive closure of a relation, where relations are represented by binary predicates:

```
inductive
  closure :: "(['a, 'a] ⇒ bool) ⇒ (['a, 'a] ⇒ bool)"
  for ℛ (infix "→" 50)
where
  gen:
    "x → y ⟹ closure (→) x y" |
  refl:
    "closure (→) x x" |
  trans:
    "⟦closure (→) x y; closure (→) y z⟧ ⟹ closure (→) x z"
```

I want to have a nicer syntax for applications of `closure`. Say I’d like to be able to write `x *(→)* y` for `closure (→) x y`. The problem is that the argument order in this notation doesn’t match the argument order of the function `closure`.

I thought that perhaps the use of `\<index>` could help. Unfortunately, the documentation of `\<index>` in the [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2018/doc/isar-ref.pdf) is very terse, and I couldn’t really make sense of it. I played a bit with `\<index>` but didn’t find any workable solution.

What puzzled me was that apparently `\<index>` gets translated to `⇘some_index⇙`, judging from some error messages I got. I tried to use `⇘ℛ⇙` to mark the position where the base relation should go, but this didn’t work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch the arguments, an abbreviation is the best choice. (`syntax`/`translations` works, too, but abbreviations should be preferred because they work in any context (locales, type classes, ...) and are type-checked.) Fortunately, `inductive` allows you to simultaneously declare abbreviations together with an inductive definition. The equations for the abbreviations have to come first. Here's how it works for your example:

```
inductive closure :: "(['a, 'a] ⇒ bool) ⇒ (['a, 'a] ⇒ bool)"
  and closure_syntax :: "['a, ['a, 'a] ⇒ bool, 'a] ⇒ bool" ("(_ ⇧*(_)⇧* _)" [999,0,999] 100)
  for ℛ (infix "→" 50)
  where
  "x ⇧*(→)⇧* y ≡ closure (→) x y"
| gen: "x → y ⟹ x ⇧*(→)⇧* y"
| refl: "x ⇧*(→)⇧* x"
| trans: "⟦x ⇧*(→)⇧* y; y ⇧*(→)⇧* z⟧ ⟹ x ⇧*(→)⇧* z"
```

The syntax element `\<index>` is rarely used nowadays, because locales achieve a similar effect and are usually more flexible. The point of `\<index>` is that you can declare a parameter as `(structure)` and this will then automatically be inserted whereever the parser sees `\<index>` in the syntax grammar. So it allows you to omit repeating the `structure` parameter, but locales usually work better.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use `syntax` and `translations`, for example:

```
syntax "_closure" :: "['a, (['a, 'a] ⇒ bool), 'a] ⇒ (['a, 'a] ⇒ bool)" ("(_ *'(_')* _)")
translations "x *(ℛ)* y" ⇌ "CONST closure (ℛ) x y"
```

These are also documented in `isar-ref.pdf`, with some examples floating around in the source theory files (a hypersearch should turn these up).